# How to find the pdf of an autocorrelated function given last measurement?

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability

Without information about the previous measurement, a random variable $X_1$ has pdf given by a Log-Normal distribution with known mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$.  If we are given that the autocorrelation coefficient for $R(t) = \alpha, t = 1$ is a, what is the pdf of $X_2$ for a given $x_1$?

How is this found more generally for a continuous variable of any pdf?